# How do I resume my session?

Tags: power-management, suspend, acpi

I have a desktop computer running Ubuntu, which is a very powerful system and I don't want it on all the time, so I would like to use the Suspend feature, but there is one problem: My computer won't resume when I press a button on the keyboard or click the mouse. What should I do to fix this problem?

[Hardinfo_report.html](http://ubuntuone.com/09KoNKaqA4SzJPwphjYAZD)

http://ubuntuone.com/09KoNKaqA4SzJPwphjYAZD

Comment: What I mean is, even if I press a key or move the mouse when the computer is suspended, it still stays in it's low-powered sleep state. This is why I can't resume... :(

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I looked on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org) and found this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11926504

Scroll down four posts to **Derek Karpinski**. He has a very organized response. Follow that and it should fix your suspend issue.

Comment: What I mean is, even if I press a key or move the mouse when the computer is suspended, it still stays in it's low-powered sleep state. This is why I can't resume... :(

Comment: Can you do a hard shutdown from the sleep state, then reboot your machine and while it's awake make the rule for the sleep state. Or does it automatically go into a sleep state on boot and you can't access your desktop?

Comment: Links to other posts are fine, but putting the information into your answer here is better, in the event that the link dies.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lord of Time. I will be sure to remember that for next time.

Comment: Didn't fix it on Ubuntu 12.04 and a Lenovo W500 with LUKS disk encryption